# Not able to change Hive Warehouse directory

Tags: azure, hive, azure-data-lake

I changed
**hive.metastore.warehouse.dir** 
to a **custom hdfs location** in ambari,
the config files are updated and cluster has been  restarted ,but still when i create tables  they are still pointing to the old warehouse directory location only.

previous warehouse directory

**/hive/warehouse**

My custom warehousedirectory

**adl://storageaccount.azuredatalakestore.net/hivewarehouse**

Comment: welcome to crapache software foundation

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if you're looking for this answer... If you want to create a hive table stored in a custom hdfs location... Then while creating the table use LOCATION keyword.
Eg:

```
Create table <name> (
a string,
b bigint)
Row format delimited
Fields terminated by ','
LOCATION '<custom HDFS location>
```

Comment: I want to change the warehouse location